# User profiles custom css

Tags: php, javascript, css

In the site i'm developing i would like to have users set their own custom "css" on their profile pages.

For example, i give users the ability to select a background color for `<body>` with a js color picker.

Then with php i create a 'css-ready' string and save it on db.

What i am asking is: how i can make this css apply everytime a user enter another user profile?

Probably will be there a lot of thing a user can customize, so there will be a big css string and i need something that will be cross browser and if possible that work also without javascript..

Thank you.

Comment: I can't really see what is the question.

Comment: That depends entirely on how you build your site. Without more details this question is unanswerable.

Comment: for starters you can always save their CSS preference in the database, and just replace the content of the CSS file with their preference, every time they logged in.

Comment: The question is clear. When i open up the profile page of a user in my site, in my php function while fetching the db for information about the user i fetch also the custom css string. So i have it inside a variable. The question is.. How can i make apply this string as a css to customize that user page when it's viewied? I could do that in js, but i prefer a server side solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this is user-profile.tpl.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($account->user_css)){
?>
<style>
<?php echo $account->user_css; ?>
</style>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a php file with header for content-type text/css which echos the CSS according to one fetched from Database, you could add default CSS to your website and just create a last in list of link tags the path to that php files, this way you have a default CSS to fall back and customized CSS to be applied on top of default if defined any..

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Handler in asp.net. I am sure there will be similar solution available in PHP also. First you need to save the style properties in a database for each user. Make sure that the syntax of the styles (selector name, curly brackets, semi-colons, etc.) are in order. You can get the user information from session object or pass the variable with query string to the handler.

The response received from the handler can directly be put between  tags as content type - text/css like this:

And with this you should be ready to go!

However, it will lead to performance losses as everytime the page loads, the entire file will be loaded (in normal css file, it is loaded only once). It will be a better idea to save only those items in database which you really want your user to customise. You may cascade it with your parent css file for better performance.